# ajax url for jstree on couchdb (via list function)

Tags: ajax, list, couchdb, jstree

I have a CouchDB list function returning the html for the jstree. I am not sure if the url in my HTML form, to invoke the list is correct, since the jstree doesn't render. (with the same html pasted locally, it does). CouchDB is running on localhost.

The location of my list function is standard, "appname/app/lists/myList.js". I have tried several combinations of url, on the lines of "/appname/_design/appname/_list/listname/viewname".

What should be the correct form ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, since I couldn't find a definite answer for rendering jstree with dynamic data using a CouchDB list, I went the other way and used after.js functionality in evently.

This is for anyone who might find it useful. This is what worked for me,

- get the data using data.js
- render it as `<ul><li/></ul>` in mustache.html
- in after.js write the function for jstree as shown in the [jstree documentation for html_data plugin](http://www.jstree.com/documentation)

  (after.js looks like this 
    `function (e) {

  $('.mytree').jstree({ 
      "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data", "checkbox" ]
  });
     }`

Answer (score 1):

The format should be as follows:

`GET /db/_design/design-doc/_list/list-name/view-name`

I copied this directly from the [CouchOne Documentation](http://techzone.couchbase.com/sites/default/files/uploads/all/documentation/couchbase-api-design.html#couchbase-api-design_db-design-designdoc-list-listname-viewname_get).

Comment: Thanks, I had tried it, in vain :(  I am beginning to wonder if it may be some other problem. Since a test href on the page with url "_list/list-name/view-name" gives me the resulting html/json according to what I return. It's when I give the same url as part of the jstree function, that jstree doesn't load.

Comment: You mentioned "appname" in place of of "db" and "design-doc" before, are you sure you're using the right name in both places?

Comment: I used the url with appname and _design directly on the browser, which then gave me back the expected result. Since the same url (with the _design/) doesn't work from href, I tried the url starting with _list/, it returns the result in plain text. The problem however occurs when I give the jstree these urls (now I have tried all possible combinations :( ) as ajax setting.  So, now I am trying to get the data(query and data.js), render it as an html <ul><li> as required by jstree and then convert it to a tree with the jstree function in after.js. So far, no success.

Comment: You should include the exact source of either your designdoc, or your _list functions. I suspect you have something wrong there.

Comment: Thank you! It turns out that I didn't figure out the 'data' part in the following function for jstree. It appends id=0 to the list url and hence does not retrieve the required data. I removed it for now and the list invocation works fine. `$(function () {
 $("#demo3").jstree({ 
  "html_data" : {
   "ajax" : {
    "url" : "_list/listname/viewname?include_docs=true",
    "data" : function (n) { 
     return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 }; 
    }
   }
  },
  "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data" ]
 });
});`